# error 500 when i create on htaccess one error 404

Tags: php, .htaccess, http-status-code-404

How can i make it so that my htacces rules return a 404 when invalid urls are entered into the adress bar.

I use the virtualbox for one project and i try create one file .htaccess and i put one error 404 to protect my pages, but when i create my error 404 and sending to the server and refresh my page i have one error 500 on my server.

My code is this:

```
#my error 404 
ErrorDocument 404/file/404.php
```

Anyone can help me?
I don't know why this happens and I have searched on google.

Greets

Comment: put below two lines(without numbers) at top of htaccess file and check.

1)Options -Indexes 2)RewriteEngine On

Answer (score 0):

You have to wrap your path with quote to determine if it was string

```
ErrorDocument "404/file/404.php"
```

Answer (score 0):

A Little White Space causes the issue

Change this

```
ErrorDocument 404/file/404.php
```

to

```
ErrorDocument 404 /file/404.php
```

Read more [here](http://www.htaccessbasics.com/404-custom-error-page/)